# Weird behavior of chrome/safari dealing with direction:rtl

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

In Internet Explorer, FireFox and Opera code below makes a red floating box on the right with a right-aligned blue box hanging below it as expected but in WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari) the blue box is left-aligned and extends beyond the visible area. Interestingly if I remove the DOCTYPE tag these browsers act normally like other browsers. Is there any logic behind this behavior or is it just a bug, can you think of a workaround?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #top_container {
                float:right;
            }
            #red {
                background:#f00;
                color:#fff;
                padding:10px;
            }
            #blue_container {
                direction:rtl;
            }

            #blue {
                position:absolute;
                background:#00f;
                color:#fff;
                padding:10px;
                width:200px;
                direction:ltr;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top_container">
            <div id="red">
                red
            </div>
            <div id="blue_container">
                <div id="blue">
                    blue
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Huh? Right aligned? You're using "direction: rtl", that's for languages that read right to left, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "direction:rtl" also forces the renderer to lay things from right to left. What I am trying to achieve is a button (the red box) that float on the right with a hanging drop-down list (blue box) which shows and hides when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

OK, a few observations:

The text direction (rtl/ltr) is irrelevant. If you remove that styling, the situation is the same.

If you remove the red node, the situation is only slightly different, with the blue box extending even further off the viewport to the right.

Here's how I read the situation:

- `#top_container` contains only one flow element: `#red`
- `#top_container` is float: right. It is therefore positioned at the right edge of the viewport, allowing the width required by the contained flow element (`#red`).
- `#blue` is absolutely positioned, relative to #top_container, but it has no positioning. It therefore aligns on the left edge with the red box and takes up 200px in width.

All this is just what I would expect. What I can't explain is why the other browsers do it differently. Why do they align `#blue` to the right edge of `#red`? I do not see why that should be.

Anyway, you may be able to get closer to what you want by adding `right:0` to your `#blue` style.

Comment: "...It therefore aligns on the left edge with the red box and takes up 200px in width." - It should align on the right edge because the parent container has "right to left" direction, all other browsers do it this way. "you may be able to get closer to what you want by adding right:0" - In my real situation the red box is not necessarily on the far right it is some kind of component that may be anywhere on the page.

Comment: See my comment above about what I'm trying to achieve, an alternative idea would be appreciated but I am really interested to know why WebKit browsers don't act like others in this case.

Comment: The W3C spec is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes. From how I read that, WebKit in strict mode is doing it incorrectly, but it seems odd that it would be correct in quirks mode.

Comment: Apart from filing at bug with the WebKit project, I don't know that there's anything to be done except work around the issue.

Comment: Just filed a bug report. I'm currently dynamically shifting the box to the left with a negative left-margin using JavaScript to simulate the same effect which is not very elegant. Hope this is fixed soon.